# SVG zoom with svg-pan-zoom.js performance issues in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, svgpanzoom

I am using javascript svg-pan-zoom.js (https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom) libary to zoom and pan svg in web application. Zooming in Firefox is very slow and laggy, while zooming in Chrome and IE11 works very well (tested with 5MB .svg file that presents floor plan - if file is smaller, this issue is not that noticeable). Panning is working fine. I've read many topics on this issue on forum but I haven't find any solution yet. Does anybody know what is causing this problem and how to fix it?

`Example:` http://jsfiddle.net/coz3fd0L/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `refreshRate` option. Maybe you set a high number.
If not then you may set a low number (ex. 10 which means max 10 frames per second) and if may improve your problem.

Other than that I don't know of any other problems in svg-pan-zoom. At least if pan is smooth then zoom should be the same.

Maybe your SVG has a lot of edges/curves/nodes and Firefox is simply bad at resizing such things. Or it is bad at resizing large SVGs when matrix transform is used (matrix transform is used for zoom/pan in svg-pan-zoom).

**Update:** From what I see this is purely a Firefox problem (or the way it is). Just opening the SVG from your example http://imgh.us/test_51.svg takes 100% of CPU (for page scroll).

Also I did try to change matrix transform values manually (to test if it is svg-pan-zoom issue) and it is anyway very slow.

The only solution I see is to try to optimize your SVGs (maybe it is possible to make them simpler: less edges, nodes, do not render white elements...).

Comment: Changing refreshRate does not help. I edited my post by adding an example with .svg file... I don't have any idea why firefox is so slow...

Comment: I wouldn't blame the script or the browser for a poorly (or automatic) exported project from somewhere else. People must understand that there's still limits (cpu, memory, etc). Suggestion is to go deep in the actual svg structure and find out your project bugs.